# How do i know how to use the 为?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, sentence

I want to know how to use the 为, because there are cases where we dont translate it and it gets it harder so i'd like like to know the uses and effects this one provoke in the sentence.

Comment: You can find a grammar book. The usage of 为 is a little complicated.

Answer (score 3):

I am no grammar expert, but let me attempt an answer based on my level of attainment. I am sure others could do better.

This is one of the most commonly occurring and useful word in the Chinese language, just about behind 的 & 了。

The problem is, (just like 的 & 了), it is a preposition, and when used in combination it becomes a verb, a conjunction, an interrogative, (a sentence of inquiry that asks for a reply)

So it is in an actual sentence that its usages become apparent.

As a preposition it is "for"; 他的牺牲是**为**了什么?, (his sacrifice is for what?)

As a conjunction it is "because of"; 他**为**爱国以牺牲了生命, (Because of his love for country he sacrificed his life)

As a verb -- 成为 -- "become"; 他的牺牲将会**成为**传说, (His sacrifice would become a legend)

As an interrogative -- 为什么, "why", 他**为什么**牺牲自己的生命?, (why did he sacrifice his own life?)

Answer (score 2):

A good start is the [Chinese Grammar Wiki page for 为](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%E4%B8%BA), which I'll go through.  Each of the relevant webpages have multiple examples, but I'll add some in-the-field examples.

By itself, 为 basically means "for" along with some related definitions.  Perhaps the "cases where we don't translate it" arise when 为 is used within words such as [因为](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA), [为什么](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%BA%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88), [成为](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%88%90%E4%B8%BA), [行为](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%A1%8C%E4%B8%BA), [为何](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%BA%E4%BD%95), [以为](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%BA), [认为](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%AE%A4%E4%B8%BA), [作为](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BD%9C%E4%B8%BA), etc., where it doesn't mean "for" (it's just part of the word).

The simplest usage has the structure:

> 为 + Party + Verb / Adj.
>   <sub>[Expressing "for" with "wei"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22for%22_with_%22wei%22)</sub>

Examples:

1. 爸妈，今天我**为**你包饺子!<sup>[[src]](http://www.sohu.com/a/212255186_770053)</sup>  (Dad and mum, today I made dumplings **for** you!).
2. 我这次来上海**为**大家演讲<sup>[[src]](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/bacbac7c80c758f5f61fb7360b4c2e3f572725e5.html)</sup> (This time, I come to Shanghai [to] make a speech **for** everyone).
3. **为**社会**为**世人尽力<sup>[[src]](https://www.kyocera.com.cn/inamori/philosophy/philosophy20.html)</sup>  (**For** society, **for** people, strive [your] hardest)

This structure is similar to:

> 为了 ⋯⋯ ，Subj. ⋯⋯
>   <sub>[Expressing purpose with "weile"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_purpose_with_%22weile%22)</sub>

Examples:

1. **为了**您的身体健康，请少饮酒<sup>[[src]](https://m.cnkang.com/nkwk/201211/855370.html)</sup> (**For** your bodily health, please drink less alcohol.)
2. **为了**爸爸妈妈,我要努力!<sup>[[src]](https://www.jianshu.com/p/e65e7d3acca8)</sup> (**For** father and mother, I will try hard!)

It's also similar to:

> Subj. + 为 + Goal + 而 + Efforts Made
>   Subj. + 不 + 为 + Goal + 而 + Efforts Made
>   <sub>[Explaining purpose with "wei... er..."](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Explaining_purpose_with_%22wei..._er...%22)</sub>

Examples:

1. **为**自己**而**学 (Learn **for** yourself [although more like "learn **for** your own reasons"])
2. **为**中国**而**战<sup>[[src]](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%BA%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E8%80%8C%E6%88%98/10353780)</sup> (Fight **for** China)

There's also a song called [**为**爱**而**生](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%BA%E7%88%B1%E8%80%8C%E7%94%9F/12770?fr=aladdin) = "Live **for** love".

And also similar to:

> ⋯⋯ 是 + 为了 / 因为 ⋯⋯
>   <sub>[Expressing purpose with "weile"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_purpose_with_%22weile%22)</sub>

Examples:

1. 人来到世上**是为了**什么?<sup>[[src]](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/376371720.html)</sup> (Mankind is on earth **for** what?)
2. 上班**不是为了**赚钱<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1639263356454848155&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup> (Going to work is **not for** making money.)
3. 成功**是因为**态度<sup>[[src]](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/280510fb0242a8956bece42e.html)</sup> (Success is **because of** attitude.)
4. 有时候,喜欢听歌**不是因为**歌唱的好听<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1633486278994146314&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup> (Sometimes, liking to listen to a song **is not because** the song sounds good)

The final one is similar, but follows a specific pattern:

> 以 + A + 为 + B
>   <sub>[Using "yi... wei..."](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22yi..._wei...%22)</sub>

Examples:

1. **以**朋友**为**话题的文章<sup>[[src]](http://www.duanmeiwen.com/qinggan/pengyou/97771.html)</sup> (An essay **taking** [a] friend **for** [the] topic)
2. **以**我家**为**例, ...<sup>[[src]](http://jia.baidu.com/m/pages/walkthrough/index?frxcx=zxj&frsrc=rank&nid=591714_wt_jia_com)</sup> (**Take** my family **for** example, ...)

This is also used in a lot of idioms, e.g. [以黑为白](http://www.baidu.com/link?url=rpgKYwCwAhpr8DpS5JMetg28kOlhqHjlBh3k4eirY_lq5p-F4BuzdnrRg-um70XG1_qikLz-CyX7YaESzi5evAbqqmex88Jat044gz3Ug5PHzyGFtceIgUFIXu4ocq5S&wd=&eqid=87251abf00119eb6000000025e15805f) literally means something like "take black for white" implying something like "wrong is right".

Answer (score 2):

There are several usages of 為, I just list part of it. Sometimes, 為 show that things are or are done for object after 為. For example, 他為我留了一塊蛋糕。 in English: He left a piece of cake for me. This example shows that thing was done for object after 為 (我). Sometimes, 為 shows that something after 為 is used to describe something before 為. 這餐花費為1000元。 in English: This meal cost for 1000 dollars. This example shows that something after 為 (1000元) is used to describe something before 為 (這餐花費). 成為傳奇。in English: Become a legend. This example show that somethings after 為(傳奇 in English: a legend) was used to describe something before 為(成 In English: the action of becoming something).